# Best way to optimize this SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine

I'm trying to fetch 5 results of jobs per page (I'm using silex with doctrine), but the page takes about 30-40 seconds to load.

```
  $sql = "
            SELECT jobs.ID, jobs.date_added, jobs.user, jobs.title, jobsmeta.meta_value, jobs_locations_rel.county, jobs_locations_rel.city, usersmeta.meta_value, attachments.title
            FROM jobs
                JOIN jobsmeta
                    ON jobsmeta.parent_id = jobs.ID
                JOIN jobs_locations_rel
                    ON jobs_locations_rel.parent_id = jobs.ID
                JOIN usersmeta
                    ON usersmeta.parent_id = jobs.user
                JOIN attachments
                    ON attachments.ID = (SELECT meta_value FROM usersmeta WHERE parent_id = jobs.ID AND meta_key = 'user_avatar' LIMIT 1)
                ORDER BY jobs.date_added DESC LIMIT 5";
            $data = $app['db']->fetchAll($sql);
```

This would be the explain plan :
[image] 
How could I optimize this query to get the result in a shorter time?

Comment: Without more info such as what indexes there are what the explain plan is, offering suggestions would all be shots in the dark.  Provide the [explain plan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html) this query uses and what indexes exist on the tables listed.

Comment: have you done indexing for ID, parent_id, user, attachments.id

Comment: jobs.user, jobsmeta.parent_id, jobs_locations_rel.parent_id, usersmeta.parent_id, usersmeta.meta_key are all candidates for indexing. You may also be able to do away with the correlated subquery, as that query will run once for every value of jobs.ID from the outer query.

Comment: This would be the explain plan : https://i.imgur.com/w0Xo2Ud.png

Comment: One more thing: it would be helpful if you could show some example data for each table and what you'd expect to get from this query, because as it is now this query will return duplicate jobs tuples for each unique (jobsmeta, usersmeta) tuple in your projection. Also it seems odd to me that jobs.ID would be a valid value for usersmeta.parent_id.

Comment: I know it's odd that jobs.ID would be a valid value for usermeta.parent_id but that's the database I was provided with and I can make no structure modification as it's already used in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execution plan shows that only two (primary key) indexes are used. This should be improved. Apart from the primary key indexes, you should try with extra indexes on:

- jobs(user)
- jobsmeta(parent_id)
- jobs_locations_rel(parent_id)
- usersmeta(parent_id, meta_key)

The query is probably also slowed down by the sub-query, which has a peculiar `LIMIT 1`. This means that the record it retrieves might be a random one of several. This either means your database design is wanting, or that you don't care to show all related records of the *attachments* table. Using `IN (SELECT ...)` without `LIMIT` would make sure you got all those *attachments* records.

But better than using `IN`, is turning this into an additional `JOIN`, like this:

```
SELECT   jobs.ID, jobs.date_added, jobs.user, jobs.title,
         jobsmeta.meta_value,
         jobs_locations_rel.county, jobs_locations_rel.city,
         m1.meta_value, attachments.title
FROM     jobs
JOIN     jobsmeta
      ON jobsmeta.parent_id = jobs.ID
JOIN     jobs_locations_rel
      ON jobs_locations_rel.parent_id = jobs.ID
JOIN     usersmeta m1
      ON m1.parent_id = jobs.user
JOIN     usersmeta m2
      ON m2.parent_id = jobs.ID
     AND m2.meta_key = 'user_avatar'
JOIN     attachments
      ON attachments.ID = m2.meta_value
ORDER BY jobs.date_added DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Another peculiar thing: `usersmeta.parent_id` either references a `jobs.ID` or a `jobs.user` value. This looks like another flaw in the database design you might want to look at.

If the order of 'job.id' values is the same as the order of `jobs.date_added` then you could consider doing an `ORDER BY jobs.id DESC`. If not, then consider creating an index on `jobs(date_added)`.

Finally, your `order by` is not specific enough, as it allows an arbitrary sort order for records that share the same `jobs.id`. This is not related to performance, but I expect it could make paging difficult (depending on how you have implemented it). The best would be if you could have a combination of columns listed in the `ORDER BY`clause that together uniquely identify the record in the result.

Answer (score 1):

Correct indexing generally is the solution when your database is well designed. But in your case I see a (possible) problem in the query construction. As I'm not a MySQL expert, I think that other users may confirm my suspicion.

Actually, you join **ALL** the jobs with other tables in an (apparently) ONE to MANY relationship, which might produce a bigger result set to `ORDER BY` just to get the first five records added most recently.

I think you should filter in the `WHERE` clause the first most relevant jobs to reduce the `JOIN` and `ORDER BY` processing. Try it including this piece of code:

```
WHERE jobs.id IN (SELECT id FROM jobs ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 5)
```

And check that the foreign key columns you are joining and the "date_added" column have proper index.

Comment: The version of MySQL-Server(5.1.73) wouldn't permit that WHERE clause.

Comment: Can you try replacing the table in the `FROM` clause with the subquery of my answer? Just change the `SELECT id` to `SELECT *`, please.

Comment: In addition to the answer, you would want to have an index on the jobs table that has date_added(1) desc, id(2).   Then the SQL will start with 5 records vs the whole table.. and getting those 5 records is a cheap index hit

Comment: Robery567.. What error do you get when you attempt to add the where clause?  That really should work.. it has to go prior to the order by.. can you clarify what error you get?

Comment: @DaveTheRave MySQL does not accept the `LIMIT` clause when using a subquery on a `IN` operator

Answer (score 0):

You can enable mysql query cache for faster repeated queries.